# YouTube Videos Flickering

Tags: intel, youtube

I noticed that youtube videos are flickering especially when the whole image/scene is replaced by another (for example a girl dancing in one POV in a video is ok, but as soon the camera POV changes, the screen flickers and the upper half is like 10px right/left).

My CPU is Intel Celeron G3900. No dedicated gpu, but still I don't think this should be happening on 720/1080p videos.

EDIT: Screenshot attached

[image]

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: Always when pausing on youtube image is ok, will try to capture with phone

Comment: It seems like a problem with the video.

Comment: added a screenshot

Comment: Another example: https://s18.postimg.org/dgjzzdavd/Screenshot_2016_11_01_18_45_10.png

Comment: Skylake IGPs are currently very buggy in terms of driver support in Linux. If you are using Chrome, then expect flickering.

Comment: Installing the Intel Graphic Driver from Intel's website helped a bit. @Patrick - Driver Support in Linux sucks overall, but not everybody can programm this by himself...

Comment: Untested solution: https://www.linuxslaves.com/2018/09/ways-to-fix-google-chrome-screen-flickering-ubuntu-linux.html